# jQuery-UI: Can't deselect tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery-UI tabs widget and I don't want any tabs to be selected when the tabs load for the first time. I've called the tabs method with the following argument:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({selected: -1});
```

which should deselect all the tabs according to the jQuery wiki. However it doesn't work, the first tab, 'Action', is always selected. Could anyone tell me how to make sure no tabs are selected when they first load?
Thanks.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){    
      $( "#tabs" ).tabs({selected: -1}); 

});
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Classics</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Comedy</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Documentary</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Drama</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Horror</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Family</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Suspense</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Sci Fi/Fantasy</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">World</a></li>
    </ul>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
Adding `$("#tabs ul li").eq(0).removeClass('ui-state-active');` after `$("#tabs").tabs();`works. It seems to prevent the tab being selected the next time you click on it but it work fine after that. Should be able to sort that out though.

UPDATE:
Turns out all you need is `$("#tabs").tabs({ collapsible: true, active: false });` to initially deselect all tabs.

Comment: The `selected: -1` option appears to only work for older versions of jQuery UI tabs (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZnytM/). For newer versions you'd have to tinker with styling and the active option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that it might not work with jQuery-UI tabs as said in http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/Can-t-disable-all-tabs-td129542.html .

You may use jquery tabs from http://www.eduteka.org/ajax/tabs3/

And as you read down the documentation, there is a heading like
"Start with all tabs unselected/allow toggle visibility", which will be what you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, the first tab is still selected when the tabs load.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time, but unfortunately neither work for me.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that unselected example in the second link does what I want. I'll try and get it to work.

Comment: That unselected example seems to use  $('#container-10 ul').tabs({ unselected: true }); . When I tried this approach it breaks the tabs and they are displayed as a simple unordered list of links. He's using an earlier version of jquery, jquery-1.2.1, so guess the approach no longer works.

Comment: Yes probably, and consider this answer only as a suggestion as I'm sure there are jquery pros around who can solve your problem. So you may put this question up for bounty and that may help you get the answer you're looking for.